# OVER (PARTITION BY) is making the query slow

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, query-performance

I have a data

```html
report_id   report_number   event_id
"149317"    2               "3403"
"149315"    1               "3403"
"149314"    0               "3403"
"149320"    1               "3405"
"149319"    0               "3405"
"149327"    0               "3409"
```

Expected :
On the basis of `event_id` , adding a new column in result set to show the max `report_number` of that `event_id`

```html
report_id    report_number      event_id        count 
    "149317"    2               "3403"            2
    "149315"    1               "3403"            2
    "149314"    0               "3403"            2
    "149320"    1               "3405"            1
    "149319"    0               "3405"            1
    "149327"    0               "3409"            0
```

To get the above expected results, I have used the

`SELECT *, MAX(report_number) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id) count FROM myTable;`

The results are correct but this slows down my query too much. ANy other way to get the above results ?

**EDIT :**
Is theres any way to extract the max report number group by event_id in select query  ?

Comment: Performance questions are meaningless without the table schema, index information *and execution plans*. I'd bet `event_id` isn't covered by any index, which forces an extra spooling and ordering operation.

Comment: A SQL query doesn't get executed as-is. It's a script that gets compiled by the query engine and converted into streaming, scanning, seeking, ordering operations, based on the available indexes and data statistics. Those operations are compiled into an execution plan which you can easily retrieve in SSMS - just hit Ctrl+L to get an estimated execution plan. You can also display the actual execution plan when you run a query

Comment: One possible cause for delay is stale statistics. If the query engine expects 100 result rows from an operation it will pick a specific operation over another. If it encounters 100K rows though, the operator it picked will probably harm performance

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY is usually faster than PARTITION.

```
SELECT
  event_id,
  MAX(report_number) AS report_number
FROM myTable
GROUP BY event_id
```

Please report back, does this give you better performance?